# StaleElementReferenceException while navigating back in selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to crawl through some anchors within a web page using Selenium WebDriver. The approach I can think of is getting the anchors in a list and performing click on each and navigating backwards after each click. Here is my code:

```
        WebDriver webDriver=new FirefoxDriver();
        webDriver.get(SEARCH_URL);
        WebElement form2=webDriver.findElement(By.id("frmMain"));
        form2.submit();
        System.out.println(webDriver.getCurrentUrl());
        List<WebElement>doctorAnchors=webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='data']/a"));
        int count=0;
        for(WebElement anchr:doctorAnchors){
            anchr.click();
            System.out.println((count++)+" : "+webDriver.getPageSource().toString());
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            webDriver.navigate().back();
        }
```

The code just goes through the first element in Anchors, performs click, gets the page, but when I navigate backwards, it gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 169 milliseconds
```

I went through various stackoverflow posts on the same exception, and realized that it may be caused by some javascript content in the page and it seems right also because the page url is: `http://www.somepage.com/dispatch` whether I go to any anchor. I can navigate back in the web browser opened by the driver as usual. But why is this `webDriver.navigate().back()` failing? And how do I navigate back after clicking on link? Is there a way I could save the state of the driver and click and restore that state after clicking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have given below is an example for your solution. Here, I have called a method, `getElementWithIndex` to do so.. This works!!

In this example, it captures all the links under specific frame|class|id and Navigate one by one

```
driver.get("www.xyz.com");  
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(Value));
List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
int sizeOfAllLinks = elements.size();
System.out.println(sizeOfAllLinks);

for(int i=0; i<sizeOfAllLinks ;i++)
{
     System.out.println(elements.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
}

for (int index=0; index<sizeOfAllLinks; index++ )
{
     getElementWithIndex(By.tagName("a"), index).click();
     driver.navigate().back();
}

public WebElement getElementWithIndex(By by, int index)
{
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(Value));
     List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
     return elements.get(index);
}
```

Comment: @rahulserver, where is he using multiple instances of a webdriver? I only see one.

Comment: @Arran then the code is wrong. He either needs to declare driver as a static global variable or pass to getElementWithIndex(). I dont think this would work either ways although I havent tried it yet.

Comment: @rahulserver This usually works for me and a working code. I use TesNG as a Unit testing framework.

Comment: @rahulserver please try this and then let me know. Thanks

Comment: please observe that this is only a part of code [I mean snippet]; usually you declare as [private WebDriver driver;] and everyone are aware about this. I thought that you are not a newbie ;)

Comment: @PrashanthSams I am a newbie to webdriver. Wl giv a try and let u know soon! Thanks for this answer. i have already upvoted it.

Comment: lol :) I thought you have devoted my answer :) Actually I use this snippet in my projects

Comment: Usually Arran devote other anwsers' :) I want him to encourage others :) hope it sounds good.

Comment: @PrashanthSams, more of a question to the OP, he should have the knowledge to tweak your answer to how he wants it. Just blindly copying & pasting code is a secret to failure. He shouldn't be expecting you to do his work for him.

Comment: I agree you but I thought he is a stuffed person in WebDriver. Its even hard to spoon feed each and everything. I think he is okay with my answer :) Also no one will answer blindly :)

Comment: @Arran "He shouldn't be expecting you to do his work for him." It hardly takes few minutes to give a more accurate code. Its all about quality of answers on SO. A code with minor errors like this can not be deemed as a perfect answer, even though it may give a hint to the solution.

Comment: @rahulserver, sometimes you will get answers that are perfect, sometimes you won't, but you should have the ability to see what is wrong. His code was **not** wrong, it was just incomplete. He, rightly so, thought you'd see what was not there and add your own into it. However, it is absolutely clear you intend to copy and paste answers from SO for your work which is *not* what SO is for. SO is for helping you to *understand* the problem and helping you to  *solve* the problem and **not** solving the problem for you.

Comment: ofcourse @rahulserver you got the point; I too agree Arran. lets compromise at this point :)

Answer (score 3):

When you change the page you lose the reference to that element since it will not be in the DOM anymore. An easy way around this is to always get the anchors again after going back to the page. Basically get the number of anchors and do a while. In that while, always get the anchor list and from that list the anchor you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
        WebDriver webDriver=new FirefoxDriver();
            webDriver.get(SEARCH_URL);
            WebElement form2=webDriver.findElement(By.id("frmMain"));
            form2.submit();
            System.out.println(webDriver.getCurrentUrl());
            List<WebElement>doctorAnchors=webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='data']/a"));
            boolean x = false;
            int c = doctorAnchors.size();
            for(int i=0; i<c; I++){
                 if(x){

List<WebElement>doctorAnchors=webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='data']/a"));
                  }
            curElement = doctorAnchors.get(i);

            curElement .click();
            System.out.println((count++)+" : "+webDriver.getPageSource().toString());
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            webDriver.navigate().back();
            x = true;
            doctorAnchors = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
             }
```

I achieved it this way. :)